# Using regex to search for keywords at the beginning of words only

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a searching system that splits the keyword into chunks and searches for it in a string like this:

```
var regexp_school = new RegExp("(?=.*" + split_keywords[0] + ")(?=.*" + split_keywords[1] + ")(?=.*" + split_keywords[2] + ").*", "i");
```

I would like to modify this so that so that I would only search for it in the beginning of the words.

For example if the string is:

```
"Bbe be eb ebb beb"
```

And the keyword is: `"be eb"`

Then I want only these to hit `"be ebb eb"`

In other words I want to combine the above regexp with this one:

```
var regexp_school = new RegExp("^" + split_keywords[0], "i");
```

But I'm not sure how the syntax would look like.

I'm also using the split function to split the keywords, but I don't want to set a length since I don't know how many words there are in the keyword string.

```
split_keywords = school_keyword.split(" ", 3);
```

If I leave the 3 out, will it have dynamic length or just length of 1? I tried doing a

```
 alert(split_keywords.lenght);
```

But didn't get a desired response

Comment: http://www.rubular.com/ is a great site to test your regexps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the special [***word boundary***](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) character `\b` to match the beginning of a word. To create the expression for an arbitrary number of keywords, you can generate it in a loop.

```
var regex = '';

for(var i = split_keywords.length;i--; ) {
    // two slashes are needed to insert `\` literally
    regex += "(?=.*\\b" + split_keywords[i] + ")";
}

var regexp_school = new RegExp(regex, "i");
```

I'm not sure about performance, but you can also consider to use `indexOf` to test whether a substring is contained in a string.

**Update:**

If `\b` does not work for you (because of other "special" characters), and all your words are separated by a white space, you can use

```
"(?=.*\\s" + split_keywords[i] + ")"
```

or

```
"(?=.* " + split_keywords[i] + ")"
```

**But** for this to work you have to *prepend* the text you are searching in with a white space:

```
" " + textYouSearchIn
```

or you are write a more complex expression:

```
"(?=(^|.*\\s)" + split_keywords[i] + ")"
```

Comment: i dont think ie likes indexOf

Comment: @Alexander: I don't know. It is supported (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53xtt423(v=vs.85).aspx) But I don't know in which version.

Comment: @Alexander: In which sense didn't it work? Do you get any error? Have you checked that `regex` looks fine?

Comment: @Alexander: So it does not match the beginning of the words? Or what do you want? If you are not specific then no one can help you.

Comment: first of all the first splitted keyword works just as a (?=.*keyword), but when the second word is typed it gets no hits what so ever :/ and the regexp looks like this : (?=\bteknisk)(?=\bkyber).* which should match teknisk kybernetikk

Comment: @Alexander: Ah my mistake. You have to keep `.*` in your regex.... I updated my answer. And actually, I don't think you need `.*` at the end.

Comment: i tried with and without .* at the end, and i also added .* in the regexp like u showed, the keyword "n" still gives me hits like "Alteidet skole Kvænangen" which contains no n at the beginning at all but i think i understand whats going on, there is an "æ" in front of the n, which is a norwegian word, i think the /b treats only A-Za-z0-9_ as word characters. does it exist a simple work around this?

Comment: i kinda want it to treat every character except for the whitespace

Comment: @Alexander: I see. Then you just replace `\\b` with `\\s` or ` ` (blank) **and** you have to prepend your text with a blank (otherwise the regular expression would never match the first word).

Comment: @Alexander: Or you write a more complex expression, everything is in my updated answer.

Comment: replacing \\b with \\s wont result in hitting "NTNU - Norges teknisk naturvitenskaplige universitet" when the keyword is ntnu, nvm i'll just stick to the regular .* :) thanks for the help tho, very appriciated!

Comment: the last one "(?=(^|.*\\s)" + split_keywords[i] + ")"
 works really good, im going to analyze it and learn why it works! :D thanks alot!

Comment: @Alexander: You're welcome :) I can tell why it works: It matches *either* the beginning of the string, *or* what we considered now as a word boundary (space). But if possible I would suggest you just prepend the string. I think the last expression adds some unnecessary work to the regular expression engine, as always only one word can be at the beginning of the string (obviously). But whatever works best for you :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple points. First, you need to anchor the regex to the start of the string. Otherwise, if there is no match, there are a *LOT* of combinations that the regex engine must try before declaring a match failure (it must check *all* of them, in fact). Second, when splitting the string, use `/\s+/` instead of a single space - this prevents getting empty matches in the resulting array in case there are multiple spaces between any keywords. Third, if there *are* empty strings in the array of keywords, you do not want to add them to the regex. Felix's solution is pretty close to the mark, but does not actually match the string once all the positive lookahead assertions are finished. That said, here's my proposed solution:

```js
var split_keywords = school_keyword.split(/\s+/);
var regex = "^"; // Anchor to start of string.
for (var i = 0, len = split_keywords.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (split_keywords[i]) { // Skip empty keyword strings.
        regex += "(?=.*?\\b" + split_keywords[i] + ")";
    }
}
regex += ".*$"; // Add ending to actually match the line.
var regexp_school = new RegExp(regex, "i");
```

I've also changed the greedy quantifier to lazy. This is one case where it is applicable.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i allready have statements like this to check if the keyword is != "" && != undefined, for the rest of the advice thanks very much i will take them with me